# Reformatting Results of cor.test to dataframe

Tags: r, correlation

I am struggling with reformatting the results of a cor.test() to a data.frame.
The Results are formatted as a List but can't simply be written into a dataframe because unlist() doesn't seem to understand items of type "double".

The Results look like this:
[Results cor.test()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPme3.png)

Now I would like to reformat the results of multiple cor.tests into a dataframe with data.name as columnnames, and all other list items in individual rows. This should then look something like this:

```
                 data.name1      data.name2     
   statistic     5.390954        xxxxxxxxx
   p.value       7.00845e-08     xxxxxxxxx
   estimate      0.1612965       xxxxxxxxx
   null.value    0               xxxxxxxxx
   alternative   two.sided       xxxxxxxxx
   method        kendall         xxxxxxxxx
```

Sorry for this Beginner's Question but I am really struggeling to get this somehow and already researched for hours. I am very grateful for any help.

Comment: Maybe simple `broom::tidy(DATA)` will do the trick (requires package `broom`)? Also, [this is a possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23022805/cor-test-into-data-frame-in-r)

Comment: Lets say cors is your result from cor.test. You might wanna try `do.call(rbind, cors)`

Comment: @mmn, yes if `cors` is a list of `cor.test` results, and you use `cbind`, you get more or less what OP wants. I'd personally go for `broom` though.

Comment: @Axeman, `cor.test` itself returns a list, so it should be a good start to try `do.call(rbind, cors)` Havent checked `broom::tidy` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tidy approach:

```
library(broom)
library(purrr)

l <- list(
  c1 = cor.test( ~ hp + qsec, mtcars),
  c2 = cor.test( ~ hp + mpg, mtcars)
)

map_dfr(l, tidy, .id = 'id')
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 9
>   id    estimate statistic p.value parameter conf.low conf.high method
>   <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <int>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr> 
> 1 c1      -0.708     -5.49 5.77e-6        30   -0.848    -0.477 Pears~
> 2 c2      -0.776     -6.74 1.79e-7        30   -0.885    -0.586 Pears~
> # ... with 1 more variable: alternative <chr>
> ```

In your example output, everything will have to be coerced to characters, which is not a very nice way to store numeric outcomes such as regression coefficients and p-values.