# What is this syntax, and how do I use it?

Tags: r

I came across this syntax from a [previous question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53771931/3212698), and I am unfamiliar with it.
However, it seems to work pretty good and I've been able to work out how to use it, but that doesn't mean I understand it.

Is this base R, or a library?

```
cor.test( ~ hp + qsec, mtcars)
```

I am referring to the usage of `~`, and the subsequent use of `+` in the call, and how that allows the specification of columns in a dataframe.

Comment: try `help(formula)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that lead me to the right trail. So the reason this is supported in `cor.test()` is because it has a `formula` argument? The thing I still don't get is why `~ a + b` is interpreted to `x = a, y = b`. I would understand if `a ~ b` could be used, but `cor.test()` doesn't like that notation.

Comment: `a~ b` would mean more like a as a function of b.   `~ a + b` means something like using a and b as the variables.

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies a lot. Feel free to post as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The help page for `cor.test` lists one form of the function as
        `cor.test(formula, data, subset, na.action, ...)`
and in the description of the arguments it says:
        formula:    a formula of the form ~ u + v
`~ hp + qsec`  is a formula, so you can get a lot of information by looking at the help page  `help(formula)`. However, that page emphasizes formulas of the form `a ~ b` which can be interpreted as something like "a as a function of b".  This formula (`~ a+ b`) has no dependent variable. It can be interpreted as something like "using the variables a and b".